# How to say that "I've been communicating by email with someone"?

Tags: expressions

I want to communicate that I've been receiving and sending emails from/to an specific person, is there a common expressions to say this? For example:

- I've been talking by email with him
- We have been communicanting each other by email
- We have been emailing each other
- Other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We have been communicating *with* each other by email.

is fine in most cases.

> We have been emailing each other.

is OK but using *communicating* is better as it means you are having an active discussion, rather than just sending emails back and forth.

> I've been talking by email with him.

I would not use *talking* since you talk on the phone, not by email.

Comment: Except: *talking* is used in a generic sense of 'communicating'. Just like we often **say** something even though we are typing, not speaking...

Comment: I would apply that colloquial use of "talking" to more immediate forms of electronic communication, such as "chat" (instant messaging). The indeterminate wait times for email often do not resemble the interactive character of "talking".